# Change part of string by iterating over a list

Tags: python, string

I have four lists of coordinates (2x lat, 2x long) of the same length (two contain start node and the other contain the destination node).

For each index of the first two lists I calculate the distance to the same index of the other two lists with the help of OpenTripPlanner and requests.get.

**I want my code to change the coordinates automatically in the query and iterate over the lists I have but as this is a string, I have no idea how to do this.**

Does somebody knows what the simplest way is?

Thanks a lot!

```
import requests
import json
import xlrd
from os.path import join as pjoin
import numpy as np

samples = pjoin('Data Brussel', 'Coordinates_Samples.xls') 
wb = xlrd.open_workbook(samples)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

amount = 118

lat_sample = []
for i in range(amount):
    lat_sample.append(sheet.cell_value(i+1, 8))
    np.array(lat_sample)

long_sample = []
for i in range(amount):
    long_sample.append(sheet.cell_value(i+1, 9))
    np.array(long_sample)
    
lat_hos = []
for i in range(amount):
    lat_hos.append(sheet.cell_value(i+1, 10))
    np.array(lat_hos)

long_hos = []
for i in range(amount):
    long_hos.append(sheet.cell_value(i+1, 11))
    np.array(long_hos)
 
for i in range(amount):
    long_from = long_sample[i]
    lat_from = lat_sample[i]
    long_to = long_hos[i]
    lat_to = lat_hos[i]

car = requests.get("http://35.205.249.41:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=50.8512205,4.3451959&toPlace=50.857195,4.344751&mode=CAR&date=12-29-2020&time=08:00:00")
test = car.json()
print(json.dumps(test['plan']['itineraries'][0]['duration'], indent = 4))
print(json.dumps(test['plan']['itineraries'][0]['walkDistance'], indent = 4))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the url string by setting it up like this

```
car = requests.get("http://35.205.249.41:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=" + str(50.8512205,4.3451959) + "&toPlace=" + str(50.857195,4.344751) + "&mode=CAR&date=12-29-2020&time=08:00:00")
```

you'll have to change the coordinates to variables, for example

```
car = requests.get("http://35.205.249.41:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=" + str(x1,y1) + "&toPlace=" + str(x2,y2) + "&mode=CAR&date=12-29-2020&time=08:00:00")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide some more detail on how you're trying to manipulate the string I may be able to provide a more clear answer, because if you're just trying to manipulate a string you can iterate over it like a list:

```
>>> test = "Hello World"
>>> for i in test:
...   print(i)
```

For more complex iterations over patterns in text you may want to consider regex

```
>>> x = re.findall('\w+', test)
>>> x
['Hello', 'World']
```